# object.anchorX and object.anchorY not working corona SDK

Tags: rotation, coronasdk

I have an image as in figure():

[image]

I'm trying to rotate it with respect to the `X` mark inside the circle. So, I tried the 
`object.anchorX` and `object.anchorY` properties. But it isn't working(ie., the anchor point isn't changing) :(

My code is:

```
local secondHand = display.newImageRect( "clock-hands-hi-v1.png", 412, 64 )
secondHand.anchorX = 0.223
secondHand.anchorY = 0.5
secondHand.x = 160
secondHand.y = 240

timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function() secondHand.rotation = secondHand.rotation + 6; end, 0 )

-- two reference lines
line = display.newRect(159,0,1,480)
line:setFillColor(255)

line = display.newRect(0,239,320,1)
line:setFillColor(255)
```

My corona version is the latest one:  `2013.1202 (2013.8.28)`
Anyone pls identify what is wrong with my code. Pls, pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you already figured it out but anchorX and anchorY are supported starting with build #2013.2076.

The build 2013.1202 seems to still use Graphics 1.0.
You should download the last public version of corona if you want to use them or use any stuff of the Graphics 2.0 update.

You can find it here : [corona sdk download](https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/coronasdk)